# checked out cucumber project with weird eclipse compilation error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, cucumber

I checked out the cucumber parent and all its subprojects.

Now I have a weird compilation error that shows org.junit4 cannot be resolved -

I removed the 4 from org.junit since I recalled it was a hack for some issues a while ago and the junit error went away..

Now I am stuck on the next line i.e.

```
org.mockito;bundle-version="1.9.5",
```

the manifest.mf looks like this with a error message on last but one line.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Cucumber Editor Test
Bundle-SymbolicName: cucumber.eclipse.editor.test
Bundle-Version: 0.0.11.qualifier
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Fragment-Host: cucumber.eclipse.editor
Require-Bundle: org.junit;bundle-version="4.12",
 org.mockito;bundle-version="1.9.5",
 org.hamcrest;bundle-version="1.1.0"
```

Comment: Looks like it requires a 'org.mockito' plugin, do you have that installed?

Comment: added a dependency but you mean a plugin

Comment: @greg-449 I added the plugin available under mockito name in marketplace but no luck so far :(